# Android GridView Adapter shows blank view

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, adapter

I need to have the items in my GridView as individual objects, that can repaint themselves, for example show a progress bar when they are downloading the game they are representing. So i created a wrapper for View.
The problem is that the grid item does not show at all.
For simplicity I've only added one image in the `LibraryAlbumView`.
if I `setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);` I see this green background in the grid cell, but not anything else.
In my wrapper:

```
public class LibraryAlbumView extends LinearLayout {
private Context context;
public LibraryAlbumView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    ImageView image;
    image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.delete));
    this.addView(image);

}
```

and my Adapter code is:

```
public class LibraryAlbumAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;

public LibraryAlbumAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        gridItem = new LibraryAlbumView(context);
        return gridItem;
            } else {
            return (LibraryAlbumView) convertView;
    }
```

however if i change the wrapper to `LibraryAlbumView extends ImageView`
and in its constructor i change to:

```
            super(context);
    this.context = context;
    setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(
            R.drawable.delete));
```

I do see the image there

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's because you haven't overridden other important methods in your adapter like `getCount()`.  Since the default implementation of `Adapter` returns zero, the GridView thinks you have no items to show.

As well as the above information, it looks like you're not setting `LayoutParams` for the `ImageView` and so the `LinearLayout` doesn't know how to present it and chooses to give it zero width and height, which would explain why you're seeing the green background and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't included the getCount() just to simplify the questions, yes it is in the code otherwise it wouldn't compile. I did try setting the width and height like this   this.addView(image,200,200);
but it didn't help

Comment: Have you tried doing it with LayoutParams like this:  `addView(image, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))`  ?

Comment: Also set LayoutParams on the LinearLayout itself when you return it from `getView()` in the Adapter